# How to enable Loopback 4 API Versioning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, version, loopback

How to enable API versioning on IBM Loopback 4 framework, where each API version will have different JSON response.

Comment: The only which I've found is to create a separate controller for new version of APIs and use it. You can use your exisiting models, repositories and services though as suited. The entrypoints anyways are the controllers so versioned controllers is the only way out right now.